# In Nginx, how to match and entire URL and Query String and redirect to a URL and Query String

Tags: regex, nginx, seo, nginx-location

I have been searching for a while now, trying work arounds and haven't come up with anything useful.

I have a (large) list of URL's from an site migration and need to match the entire URL + Query String and redirect to another URL.

As far as I can see the following only matches `/mens`, but not the rest of the query string.

```
rewrite "^/mens?brand%5B%5D=27&section%5B%5D=5&price-min=0&price-max=2000&sort=newest"  "/t/gender/men" permanent;
```

The reason it's important is that I have a bunch of similar URL's with slightly different Query Strings, which need to be redirected, similar to below, but actually work.... :-/

```
rewrite "^/mens/shop?q=road+map+polo"       "/t/category/golf-knits"    permanent;
rewrite "^/mens/shop?q=six+pocket+pant"     "/t/category/golf-pants"    permanent;

#etc... ad noiseam
```

Thanks in advance, 
Paul.

Comment: Not a programming question. Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters

Comment: Next time search for "nginx rewrite request argument"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$request_uri` variable contains the entire URL. You could use a `map` to translate it into a redirection.

```
map $request_uri $target {
    ~*^/mens/shop\?q=road\+map\+polo   /t/category/golf-knits;
    ~*^/mens/shop\?q=six\+pocket\+pant /t/category/golf-pants;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($target) { return 301 $target; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.