# nginx url rewrite from and to the same php file

Tags: php, nginx, hyperlink, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect or rewrite a link in my nginx site config, but i cant get it to work properly. I have already tried this:

```
rewrite ^/index.php?threads/this-is-a-link.22/$ /index.php?threads/some-redirect.34/ permanent;
```

Can you elaborate on how I can achieve this?
thank you very much!

Comment: Where are you trying to redirect from and to? From `index.php?threads/this-is-a-link.22` to `index.php?threads/some-redirect.34`?

Comment: `rewrite` uses a *normalized URI* which does not include the query string (anything following the `?`). You can use a `map` directive on the `$request_uri` variable - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083010/in-nginx-how-to-match-and-entire-url-and-query-string-and-redirect-to-a-url-and/36084603#36084603) for an example.

Comment: yes exactly :-)