# Matching every URL which is like /?= followed by a number

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I need to match all URLs which are similar to domain.com/?= followed by some random numbers like domain.com/?=123123.
I'm trying this regex which is not working in nginx /?=[0-9]* it some equivalent like location ~ ^/(?)(=)([0-9]+)$ is not matching what i want either.

Comment: you'd likely need to escape the `?` as it means the previous match is optional (i.e. zero or one repeats).  also that's a strange URL, normally you get key/value pairs after a `?`, like `path?a=b&c=d`

Comment: @SamMason Yeah I know its a strange URL, I'm receiving a DDOS attack on URLs with this pattern and I want to deny them, That's why I'm trying to catch it

Comment: maybe something like: `\?=[0-9]+` (the backslash before the `?` is an "escape character", see https://regexr.com/7mpmu

Comment: @SamMason Yeah that works on normal regex but using regex in nginx location is different and this doesn't work there

Comment: your use of `[0-9]*` says to match zero or more repeats, matching against zero repeats is probably not what you want, unless you've got something else following it

Comment: oh, yup, the location doesn't contain the query string, so you'd need to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/36084603/1358308

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has already been answered here: https://serverfault.com/q/160790